# How to pass a value of selected option in one file to functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a dropdown on home page whose value i want to use in a function in functions.php How should i proceed i have no idea. This is the code i am using

```
<form action="single-product.php" method="POST">
          <select name="selected-country" id="country-opt">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose Your Country</option>
            <?php
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product',                             
                               'posts_per_page' => 4,                           
                             );
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                if($loop->have_posts()):while($loop->have_posts()):$loop->the_post();               

                $term  = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'product_cat');             

            ?>


            <option  value="<?php echo $term[0]->name; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php echo $term[0]->name; ?></option>
            <?php 
                endwhile;
                endif;
            ?>
          </select> 
      </form>

<a id="submit-btn" href="">Submit</a>

<script>
        document.getElementById("country-opt").onchange = function() {
            if (this.selectedIndex!==0) {
               document.getElementById("submit-btn").href=this.children[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('href');
            }        
        };       
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want to use the function in the target script when the form is submitted?

Comment: @Jeff i want to get the value of selected option in single-product.php so that i can store it then in some global variable or some session  and then use that variable in functions.php

Answer (score 1):

You could add it to the URI and pass it from the option value like this

```
  <option  value="<?php echo $term[0]->name; ?>" href="<?php the_permalink() . '?t=' . $term[0]->name; ?>"><?php echo $term[0]->name; ?></option>
```

If sessions work in your WordPress - @kaiser has pointed out that they don't, though they have worked for me to solve a similar problem in the past,
you could use `$_SESSION['my-selected-country'] = $_GET['t'];` to get it back.

or make `$_SESSION['my-selected-country'] = $_POST['selected-country'];`

By making it into a session variable it should then work as a global and be available in `functions.php`.

The hidden input method below will work in either case whether sessions work or not. Thanks to @kaiser for the "heads-up".

If you add a submit button rather than using an `<a href` you would be able to pick the value up in the target page. I think `single-product.php` is actually a page part template so you might want to make a new page for your button to submit to rather than pointing to a template part.

That would mean you could make the value of `selected-country` just the href you want, together with a query string and use that in the page you submit to by collecting it as a `$_POST` PHP variable

```
  <option  value="href='<?php the_permalink() . '?t=' . $term[0]->name; ?>'><?php echo $term[0]->name; ?></option>
```

You could add a submit button or you could make the existing link a submit span:

```
<span id="submit-btn" onclick="submit_this();">Submit</span>
```

With a little JavaScript script in your header

```
function submit_this(){
document.form.submit();
}
```

add `id="form"` to your form as well.

You could add an `onchange` event to the dropdown

```
 <select name="selected-country" id="country-opt" onchange="set_url(this.value)">
```

and using the last version above have a little `onchange` script which says

```
function set_url(url_value){
document.getElementById('submit-btn').href = url_value;
}
```

Remember to define `var url_value='';` in JavaScript your header or it will fail. All of the script bits should go in your header, or better, be enqueued and put into your functions.php

If you want the URI and the text value of `$term[0]->name;` you would need to make a hidden input called - say `option-text`

```
<input type="hidden" id="option-text" name="option-text" />
```

and add to your onchange event function script

```
document.getElementById('option-text').value = this.innerHTML;
```

and pick that up as `$_POST['option-text'];`

Using JavaScript to send values to a hidden input in this way is very commonly used to transfer values from JavaScript to PHP.

As you will be picking up submitted variables it is essential to ensure that they are cleaned up and escaped to prevent inject attack.

Comment: WordPress does not use `$_SESSION` – it even actively resets and nukes it.

Comment: @kaiser funny it worked happily on one of my sites. Could he get a way with just making it global WordPress style?

Comment: Ok, [**here** is a link to the part in WordPress](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/956627ff83322bd04b068326dd91a3274c5b2a25/wp-includes/load.php#L31-L46) core where `$_SESSION` gets unset (alongside other globals). Also, I don't really understand why would one need JavaScript for that. Simple POST/GET should be more than enough.

Comment: @kaiser I agree but was attempting to answer with as many parts of the OPs question/comments referenced as possible and he was using JavaScript. I suppose if a submit button is not wanted then JavaScript would be needed at least for the submit.

Comment: You can always submit a `<form>` by hitting the <kdb>Enter</kbd> button. But I agree, especially on your answers last sentence.